# Screen brightness keys don't work

Tags: 12.10, shortcut-keys, screen, brightness

I read the same problems but I didn't find an answer.

I can change my brightness by slider in "brightness and lock" but when I press the key button it goes to lowest level and when I press the other button it just become lighter just one level and I just can switch between this two dark levels.

Is there anyway I can repair it without changing it manually?

Comment: Can you add the model of laptop it is? This question is unanswerable without knowing more about the hardware

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's still watching this post, I found an answer to this question and posted an answer here:
[Cannot change brightness](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319418/cannot-change-brightness/337511#337511)

Hope this helps.