# Cannot change brightness

Tags: 13.04, graphics, display, brightness

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and my graphics card is Nvidia GF 620M. For some reason, Ubuntu is using the Ivy Bridge processor. It works fine, though.

The only issue I'm facing is the brightness. I can't change it. I'm trying to change it through the hot keys in my Acer, but it is not changing. Anyway to do that?

Comment: Please provide us with your PC model.

Comment: Acer aspire v5-571

Answer (score 0):

I have found a cure for this which has worked for me

- Ubuntu 13.04
- **Packard Bell**

  - Intel® Core™ i3-2350M CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4
  - Intel® Sandybridge Mobile
  - 64-bit

### THE ORIGINAL PROBLEM

The <kbd>F11</kbd> and  <kbd>F12</kbd> control the brightness, but although the tooltips showed that the brightness was changing, the screen didn't change.

[image][image][image][image]

### THE CURE

I cured this by opening and editing the grub menu.

1. Open Terminal with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
2. I typed in `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`, entered my password
3. I changed the line which read `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"`
4. Saved and Closed gedit.
5. in Terminal I updated the Grub with `sudo update-grub`
6. I re-booted the laptop

Everything is now working.