# Ubuntu 13 does not recognize keyboard shortcut to control the screen brightness

Tags: shortcuts

My ubuntu 13 does not recognize the notebook shortcut to increase or decrease the brightness of the screen. Anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Comment: I do not want to have to use the terminal every time I want to change the brightness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a fix for this and posted it on [Cannot change brightness](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319418/cannot-change-brightness/337511#337511)

basically:

1. Open Terminal with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
2. I typed in `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`, entered my password
3. I changed the line which read `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"`
4. Saved and Closed gedit.
5. in Terminal I updated the Grub with `sudo update-grub`
6. I re-booted the laptop

Comment: Ok I'm not with my notebook now to test but still thank you for answering me.

Comment: If you've posted an answer on another question, you should mark this question as a duplicate.